# className gets removed clicking outside the div

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code. By default Patriots will have btn-primary color which is blue and packers will have the default color of white. The color changes upon selection between the two buttons but when I click outside the div both button change to white. Really appreciate any suggestion. I am an absolute beginner btw.

```
 class something {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        clicked: false
      };
    }

    toggleView() {
      this.setState({
        clicked: true
      });
    }
    render() {
      var classRender = "btn-primary";
      classRender = this.state.clicked ? "btn-primary" : "btn-primary selected ";
      return (
        <div>
          <button
            className={classRender}
            type="button"
            onClick={e => this.toggleView()}
          >
            Patriots
          </button>
          <button
            className="btn-primary"
            type="button"
            onClick={e => this.toggleView()}
          >
            Packers{" "}
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested the code below it will update the button with `selected` class `onClick` and will keep selected if clicked outside

```
export default class Toggle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            patriotsSelected : true
        }

        this.patriotsSelected  =  this.patriotsSelected.bind(this);
        this.packersSelected  =  this.packersSelected.bind(this);
    }

    patriotsSelected(){
        this.setState({patriotsSelected : true})
    }

    packersSelected(){
        this.setState({patriotsSelected : false})
    }



    render() {
        var patriotsClass = this.state.patriotsSelected ? "btn-primary selected" : "btn-primary";
        var packersClass = this.state.patriotsSelected ? "btn-primary" : "btn-primary selected";
        return (
            <div>
                <button className={patriotsClass} onClick={this.patriotsSelected}  >
                    Patriots
                </button>
                <button className={packersClass} onClick={this.packersSelected} >
                    packers
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: hey. Your solution lags when toggling between the buttons. Also, the class gets removed when I click outside the div.

Comment: sorry i thought you are trying to achieve that .... i updated the code to handle click outside

Answer (score 0):

So what's happening is even if you click the Packers button, the Patriots button still thinks it's clicked, because your assignment of 'this.state.clicked' is ambiguous in the `toggleView` method.

```
class something {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicked: null
    };
  }

  toggleView(team) {
    this.setState({
      clicked: team
    });
  }

  buttonClass(team) {
    var clicked = this.state.clicked;
    return (team === clicked ? "btn-primary" : "btn-primary selected ");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          className={this.buttonClass('Patriots')}
          type="button"
          onClick={e => this.toggleView('Patriots')}
        >
          Patriots
          </button>
        <button
          className={this.buttonClass('Packers')}
          type="button"
          onClick={e => this.toggleView('Packers')}
        >
          Packers{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick response. Your solution changes the button text. I have certain css set for the button name. When I click the button the text layout of the button changes. Also, the class still gets removed when I click outside the div.